# Accessing Properties in Single Page Components - VueJS 2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to access two properties I am passing to a Single File Component like below:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ width }} - {{ height }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return { 
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height
      }
    },
    props: ['width','height']
  }
</script>
```

And here is the main.js file which I use with browserify/vueify to create build.js that I include in the my html:

```
var Vue = require('Vue')
var barchart = require('./components/barchart.vue')
var d3 = require('d3')

var e = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement(barchart)
  }
})
```

HTML File:

```
<div id="app">
    <barchart :width="20" :height="20"></barchart>
</div>
```

I should be getting an output like:

```
20 - 20
```

but instead I get

```
 -
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare the properties in the `data()` if they are properties. You should try that:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['width','height']
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked but it still is static in a way.

```
var e = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement(barchart,{
        props:{
            width: 20,
            height: 20
        }
    })
  }
})
```

How can it take values given from actual properties is beyond me. The answer is incomplete.